# Google AdWords api - Invalid version for use with report XML

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm new to AdWords API and how do I know what is wrong with my request ??  I put the logging, but don't know what is wrong here.

I only know it is 400 and it said "Invalid version for use with report XML",  but what to do next ??

The following is from the debug log

```
POST /api/adwords/reportdownload/v201502 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl, gzip
Host: adwords.google.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: Bearer ya29.ogK7VE1R0zsd_21CljV7L4wNpkeZkk9XX18m6T14cxxxx-xxx
developerToken: some-token-xxx
clientCustomerId: xxx-xxx-xxxx
skipReportHeader: true
skipReportSummary: true
X-NewRelic-ID: VQcPVF5bGwoBU1JaDgY=
X-NewRelic-Transaction: PxRTVgMBWQcJAQQHBwkEVQcHFB8EBw8RVT8=
Content-Length: 582
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------c5b963b61c100061

Parameters:
__rdxml: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<reportDefinition>
  <selector>
    <fields>Impressions</fields>
    <fields>Clicks</fields>
    <fields>Cost</fields>
  </selector>
  <reportName>Criteria performance report #56e25abec118a</reportName>
  <reportType>CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT</reportType>
  <dateRangeType>LAST_7_DAYS</dateRangeType>
  <downloadFormat>CSV</downloadFormat>
  <includeZeroImpressions>false</includeZeroImpressions>
</reportDefinition>
```

Response Code: 400
Error Message: Invalid version for use with report XML

**I'm kind of lost of what was wrong in my request, any help would be appreciated.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the v201502 version is deprecated, https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/sunset-dates#api-versions